# how to send notification to all logged in users using websockets and SockJS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-websocket, sockjs

I want to notify all logged in users that how many users are logged-in/online in my app, that was so simple I have following code to do so in configure method os WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I have simply

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/");

    }
```

and at controller side I have

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionRegistry")
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
        @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUserProfile(Model model){
List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

        List<String> usersNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Object principal: principals) {
            if (principal instanceof org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) {
                usersNamesList.add(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) principal).getUsername());
            }
        }       

        model.addAttribute("onlineUsers", "Online users are " + usersNamesList.size());
return "layout_user_profile";

}
```

I get number of online users, but not real time, I want to notify all users that some new user is logged-on/logged-off of that App, I have *@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker* annotated class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketBrokerConfigurer extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/users")
        .setHandshakeHandler(new CurrentLoggeInUserHandshakeHandler())
        .withSockJS();      
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");

    }

    class CurrentLoggeInUserHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler{


        @Override
        protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
                WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
            User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String username = user.getUsername();
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null);
        }   

    }

}
```

and my client side is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webSocketC;
    var stompClient;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        webSocketC = new SockJS('/app/users');

        stompClient = Stomp.over(webSocketC);

        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame){
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/users', function(message){
                //TODO Here
            });

        }, function(error){         
                console.log("error " +  error);         
        });     
    });
    </script>
```

with this code I get browser console output as

```
Opening Web Socket...
stomp.js:134 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:134 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:john-doe@mail.com

connected to server undefined
stomp.js:134 >>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/users
```

## Conclusion

I can not find a way to send messages to all users, whether I use *@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker* annotated class send that notification or or the client side code is the place to get the desired trick done? and how that could be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service
public class MessageService {
    @Autowired
    public SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    public void sendMessage( String message ) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend( "/topic/greetings", new Greeting("Some message") );
    }
}
```

Something like this should do.